# using detachedCriteria as a subquery for in clause

Tags: grails, subquery, grails-orm, detachedcriteria

I am trying to use a detached criteria as subquery for 'in' clause but somehow it does not work:

```
def trades = new DetachedCriteria(Trade).build {
            projections { property "tradeNbr" }
}

def activities = Activiies.withCriteria {
            'in' "tradeNumber", trades
}
```

This is the error that I am running into:

```
2012-11-07 01:07:09,088 [http-bio-8081-exec-1] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - f228562 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria@57c4e7b2



grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassCastException: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
            at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1587)
            at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:282)
```

Comment: The documentation for the detachedCriteria says that list() is a default method but apparently it is not doing it. I was expecting 'print trades' to get the trades but it prints the object reference. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `list` is only a default in the sense that you can use it in an `each` construct like

```
trades.each {
    println it
}
```

And that's because it implements Iterable.  Otherwise you actually have to run the query with `trades.list()`. Just using `trades` refers to the DetachedCriteria object.

```
def activities = Activities.withCriteria {
    'in'("tradeNumber", trades.list())
}
```

Comment: trades.list() should work but I was hoping that the query parser would parse the trades criteria within activities and at that time expand the query within activities and call list by default.